# how to solve uipickerview 

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsmutablearray, uipickerview, xcode4.3

I have a problem with my pickerview where by clicking on the textfield it shows an empty uipickerview. I have 3 textfield where by clicking on each textfield there will be different array for each one. 
Here's the code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    tbMode.inputView = pickerView;
    tbWalkDist.inputView = pickerView;
    tbRouteOpt.inputView = pickerView;
}
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}
-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField*)textField;
{
    modeArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    if(textField.tag==1){
        [modeArray addObject:@" A "];
        [modeArray addObject:@" B "];
        pickerView.hidden = NO;
    }
    else{
        if(textField.tag==2){
            [modeArray addObject:@" 300 "];
            [modeArray addObject:@" 400 "]; 
            [modeArray addObject:@" 500 "];
            pickerView.hidden = NO;
    }
        else{
            if(textField.tag==3){
                [modeArray addObject:@" cheapest "];
                [modeArray addObject:@" fastest "];
                pickerView.hidden = NO;
            }
            else{
                pickerView.hidden=YES;
            }
        }
    }    
}
- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView;
{
    return 1;
}

- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:    (NSInteger)component
{
    tbMode.text = [modeArray objectAtIndex:row];
}

- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component;
{
    return [modeArray count];
}

- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component;
{
    return [modeArray objectAtIndex:row];
}
```

pls help! where did i got wrong? is it possible that this method `-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField*)textField;` is not called? thanks

edit* i miss out these 3 line of line which is for each textfield which use to call that method in `viewDidLoad`

```
tbMode.delegate = self;
tbWalkDist.delegate = self;
tbRouteOpt.delegate = self;
```

But I'm still getting an empty picker view. how can i add these `NSMutableArray` into the the picker view
*add in `[pickerView reloadAllComponents];` the picker will display the values :)

Comment: Have you tested that it still appears if you don't hide it in your viewDidLoad method?

Comment: Also, if you want to know if certain code is reached, put some NSLog statements in there.  Eg  NSLog(@"I'm a line of code that's been executed");   And watch to see if this message is printed in the debug console.

Comment: `-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField*)textField;` is not being called what do it have to do for it to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for your output problem, you need to keep track of the uiTextField that activated. Add an ivar,

uiTextField *activeField;

set the variable to the appropriate uiTextField object in the textfield delegate method. Then replace,

tbMode.text = [modeArray objectAtIndex:row];

with,

activeField.txt = [modeArray objectAtIndex:row];

Set the ivar like so:

```
    -(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField*)textField
{
      activeField = textField;

      // all the if else logic here

}
```

Comment: I added example. just one line to add. You don't need to use the tag because you textField will always be the object you want to save.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see here where you initialize the pickerView ivar. Can I assume it is created in xib?
If so, make sure you have connected the iBOutlet and set up its delegate and datasource property to be the "file owner" or view controller as it were.

If you create the picker in the init method, post that code so we can see if those properties are set correctly.

You also must have set your controller as the delegate for the uiTextField.

Additionally, if they are not implemented elsewhere, you are missing these required protocols:

– pickerView:rowHeightForComponent:

– pickerView:widthForComponent:

Comment: yup. i did link its delegate and datasource property to the file owner. But it still show an empty pickerview

Comment: and how about the textfield(s). They need delegate set as well.

Comment: i added `[pickerView reloadAllComponents] ` by Eoin. the picker displayed the correct array

Comment: But due to `- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent: (NSInteger)component { tbMode.text = [modeArray objectAtIndex:row]; }` all my result only display on first textfield. what should i do to put it on each textfield any advice?

Answer (score 1):

Try [pickerView reloadAllComponents] after setting the new data set.

Comment: But due to `- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:    (NSInteger)component
{
    tbMode.text = [modeArray objectAtIndex:row];
}` all my result only display on first textfield. what should i do to put it on each textfield

Comment: have you added your viewcontroller as the delegate for each uitextfield? And ensured that the tags match?